# Wordpress SQL $wpdb query by order of post instead of by date

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a function that finds the siblings of a post in Wordpress, the previous three, and the next three.  However, at the  moment, it orders it by the date published, which is not what I want.  In wordpress, I have a plugin which allows the user to re-order the post, and this is how it displays on the site.  I need this query to order it not by date, but by the order of the post. Would this be possible?

```
function get_post_siblings( $limit = 3, $date = '' ) {
global $wpdb, $post;

if( empty( $date ) )
    $date = $post->post_date;

//$date = '2009-06-20 12:00:00'; // test data

$limit = absint( $limit );
if( !$limit )
    return;

$p = $wpdb->get_results( "
(
    SELECT 
        p1.post_title, 
        p1.post_date,
        p1.post_name,
        p1.ID
    FROM 
        $wpdb->posts p1 
    WHERE 
        p1.post_date < '$date' AND 
        p1.post_type = 'work' AND 
        p1.post_status = 'publish' 
    ORDER by 
        p1.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 
        $limit
)
UNION 
(
    SELECT 
        p2.post_title, 
        p2.post_date,
        p2.post_name,
        p2.ID 
    FROM 
        $wpdb->posts p2 
    WHERE 
        p2.post_date > '$date' AND 
        p2.post_type = 'work' AND 
        p2.post_status = 'publish' 
    ORDER by
        p2.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 
        $limit
) 
ORDER by post_date DESC
" );
$i = 0;
$adjacents = array();
for( $c = count($p); $i < $c; $i++ )
    if( $i < $limit )
        $adjacents['prev'][] = $p[$i];
    else
        $adjacents['next'][] = $p[$i];

return $adjacents;
```

}

Comment: If your plugin uses the database field 'menu_order' to order the posts, you could replace "post_date" with "menu_order"